# Key-Based Data Structure That Allows Mutable Keys?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

Does anyone know of any implementations of or papers about key-based data structures that allow mutable keys?

Since the key is being mutated, I'm not sure if 'key' is a correct term but I hope you understand my meaning.

My specific reason for wanting this is to be able to have as efficient as possible neighbor lookup for changing objects without needing to constantly sort parallel lists, constantly restructure a tree or similar structure, or of course deal with the complete collapse of a hashmap when its keys are mutated.

A quick, very simple usage example would be (Java HashMap syntax):

```
MutableKeyMap<Point, String> m = new MutableKeyMap<Point, String>();
Point p = new Point(5, 6)
m.put(p, "foo");
Point o = new Point(6, 6);
m.put(o, "bar");
// The points are currently neighbors, so
m.get(new Point(o.x - 1, o.y)); // returns "foo". 
m.get(new Point(p.x + 1, p.y)); // returns "bar"
// Now here is where most data structures fall apart without some reworking
o.y += 1;
m.get(new Point(o.x - 1, o.y - 1)); // Still returns "foo" because the point "foo" is mapped to has not changed
m.get(new Point(p.x + 1, p.y)); // returns null, as to be expected because o would no longer map to there
m.get(new Point(p.x + 1, p.y + 1)); // A hash map would return null here as well when it should return "bar", 
// because the data structure cannot account for the identity-changing mutation of the key. 
m.get(o); // even returns null because of this in a hash map.
// Therefore we have effectively deleted the entry. In this data structure the idea would be to maintain this link despite the mutation.
```

So ideally this data structure would allow the elegance (and if possible, the speed) provided by a map for accessing other elements in the set with respect to another element, while allowing those values by which the elements are accessed to change.

I realize this is probably asking for a "perfect" data structure, but I'm really just interested as to what there exists on this type of data structure, or any ideas that people have.

Comment: Your use case remains obscure. What do you want to achieve? Give some example operations. Do your mutated objects retain the same identity? Does the mapping depend on the values of the objects in two sets?

Comment: Just a guess but would a k-d tree suffice?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: @Justin I don't think so, because which objects neighbor which would change during the runtime, and the tree would be invalidated.

Comment: @Maltor If you are changing the thing that defines an elements position in the structure then I don't think you'll find a data structure which can accomplish what you'd like. But if you consider neighbors as the element inserted before and the element inserted after then you can probably find one. If the later is what you are after than maybe a LinkedHashMap will work.